# problem with evaluations

Tags: professionalism

I've worked for 5 years as an operator. Every year I get a very low evaluation like 85%, or some years 89%. I asked my manager about it, and he replied "you are working well, next time i will give you 95%." But when the time comes, he gives me 84%. Some other employees get more than me.

I want to send an email to the head-office regarding my evaluation ranking very low. What should I say? I really feel bad that every year I get a very low evaluation even though I work hard.

Comment: Hello "Edison". Talk to the person who evaluated you.  He is dodging your question.  Press him until you get a genuine response.

Comment: If you truly feel that the evaluation was unfair, write a letter stating your objections backed up with solid examples.

Comment: What is the consequence of a low or high rating? Do others get larger pay increases? Are others getting promoted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boss can't articulate how I can improve during performance review. Now what?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48771/boss-cant-articulate-how-i-can-improve-during-performance-review-now-what)

Comment: Working hard is not a guarantee of a high evaluation. All employees are expected to work hard, that is a minimum requirement not one of outstanding performance. If your boss is rating you lower than other people then something is wrong in what you are doing or in how your work is being perceived. You need to fix that and not whine that you wanted a higher rating.

Answer (score 2):

You claim that this is a very low evaluation, but you don't explicitly state if you've been punished or otherwise demoted because of it.  Without any tangible effect from these evaluations, there's no way for you to know how to improve, or what's keeping you from getting 90% or above.

Talk *directly* with your evaluator and ask specific questions about your performance.  Do not make this out like you want to know why you're getting marked lower than you expect; instead, steer the conversation towards tips and direct suggestions on how you can improve as a professional.  Think "professional development" instead of "evaluation".

I wouldn't recommend writing a letter or contacting anyone else on the matter, since it could result in more direct and unfavorable reviews in the future.